# Given p and q two real polynomials with q different than zero. Suppose that f = p/q is a periodic function. Show that f is constant.

Tags: calculus

Given $p$ and $q$ two real polynomials with $q$ different than zero. Suppose that $f = p/q$ is a periodic function. Show that f is constant.

**Hint:** Given a a real number such that $q(a)$ is different than zero, consider the equation:
$$p(x)-\mu q(x)=0
$$
 where $$\mu =p(a)/q(a)$$

Comment: is this a homework question? what are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach:

Let $T$ be the period of $f$.

Let $p = k\cdot q + r$, where $q,r$ are polynomials and the degree of $r$ is strictly less that the degree of $q$. Then $f(x) = k(x)+ {r(x) \over q(x)}$ for $q(x) \neq 0$.

Note that $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} {r(x) \over q(x)} = 0$. If $k$ is not a constant polynomial, we have
$\lim_{|x| \to \infty} |k(x)| = \infty$, and so $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} |f(x)| = \infty$, which would contradict $f$ being periodic. Hence $k(x) = c$ a constant.

Now suppose $r \neq 0$, then there is some point $x_0$ such that ${r(x_0) \over q(x_0)} $ is finite and non-zero. However, since ${r(x_0) \over q(x_0)}  = {r(x_0+nT) \over q(x_0+nT)} $, we obtain a contradiction by letting $n \to \infty$.

Hence $f(x) = c$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a,\mu$ be as in the OP. Then $r=p-\mu q$ is a polynomial satsifying $0=r(a)=r(a+T)=r(a+2T)=\ldots$, where $T$ is the period of $\frac{p}{q}$ (why ?), so $r$ has infinitely many roots, so $r=0$.